# Internet Explorer 8 - JS Charts

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, charts, jscharts

Company policy restricts to IE8, but jscharts does not appear to work in IE8, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: http://www.jscharts.com/ says that it is compatible with IE8+, What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: This is error I get; Message: 'window.G_vmlCanvasManager' is null or not an object
Line: 698
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: http://smartwatchsolutions.com/total/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate method for your **jscharts webpage** is to [**configure**](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/chrome-frame-faq#TOC-How-can-I-enable-Google-Chrome-Frame-for-my-site-) it to use [**Chrome Frame plugin for IE8**](http://www.google.com/chromeframe?quickenable=true).

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

This will allow your IE8 to run close to Google Chrome's browser, less IE8 limitations like CSS3.

However as [Ahmad Alfy mentions in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180077/internet-explorer-8-js-charts/14180175#comment19651719_14180077), it's suppose to work in IE8.

Comment: I din't get it work, tried the link  "Ahmad Alfy mentions in comments" but it leads me to this very page.

Comment: That link just clarifies that the jscharts is compatible with IE8. The error message you posted in comments is due to that plugin script named `flot.js`. I am not sure if both errors are related, but you'll need to debug the source of the problem. I recommend visiting W3C Online Validation Tool and check your webpage for errors [**HERE**](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I notice that the website `http://smartwatchsolutions.com/total` is loading **two** instances of jQuery on line 39 and line 142.

Comment: Also, that error file you mention about, the `flot.js`, is a plugin from 2007. You might check to see if a newer version is available since it's more than 5 years old.